# Upgrading program without keypair

Tags: anchor, program

Is it possible to upgrade a program using `anchor deploy` without having it's program keypair but being the program upgrade authority?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all upgrades can be done with only the program's public key and only the initial deployment requires the program's keypair.

Use `solana program deploy --program-id <PROGRAM_ID> <PROGRAM_PATH>` to upgrade your program without its keypair.

Note that `<PROGRAM_PATH>` is the path to the generated `/target/deploy/<PROGRAM_NAME>.so` file.